# Oracle Update takes long time while updating primary key column

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, sql-update

There is the table `EFORMDYNAMICFIELDINSTANCE` with primary key `(Enterpriseid, Ownertype, Ownerid, Itemtype, Itemid)`.

In order to change a primary key to single column i.e `EDFI_ID` we want to update this `EDFI_ID` starting with 7000000 as increment value.

This table with hardly 50000 records takes 10 hrs to update.
This is my table defination:

```
ENTERPRISEID NOT NULL NUMBER(10),
OWNERTYPE    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(60),
OWNERID      NOT NULL NUMBER(10),
ITEMTYPE     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(60),
ITEMID       NOT NULL NUMBER(10),
EDFI_ID      NOT NULL NUMBER(10),
FIELD1                VARCHAR2(2000), 
FIELD2                VARCHAR2(2000), 
...
FIELD199              VARCHAR2(2000),
FIELD200              VARCHAR2(2000)
```

Earlier we had `(ENTERPRISEID, OWNERTYPE, OWNERID, ITEMTYPE, ITEMID)` as the primary key.

Now `EDFI_ID` is my primary key column and we want to update this primary key with `(rownumber + 7000000)`. This table has approximately 50000 records and `EDFI_ID` should update as 7000000, 7000001, 7000002....7050000.

Please suggest an `UPDATE` statement which will take less time. As of now my above `UPDATE` is taking 10 hours.

Comment: what is the point of the WHERE EXISTS?  You want to update every row, right?

Comment: create new table with CATS [cats](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_create_table_select_ctas.htm)

Comment: This statement has O(N^2) performance. Use a merge statement, compute the new edfi_id in the using clause and use the new computed edfi_id in the "matched" clause and skip the "not matched" clause. This 'll get you back to O(N) performance.

Comment: i hope you understood my requirement

Comment: if you think we haven't then please say why.

Comment: I don't mean that way

Comment: Just want to ask any other way to achieve this through update without using temporary table

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your problem is the repeated execution of your subqueries.  I'm not even sure the second one (inside the WHERE EXISTS) is doing anything useful.

1. Strip out the WHERE EXISTS - that will eliminate half the effort.  If that doesn't help then...
2. create a temporary mapping table that holds all your existing primary key values, along with your new PK value.  Create a unique index on your five PK columns.  Then use the mapping table in the subquery

Just to elaborate on my second suggestion :

```
CREATE TABLE temp_pk_mapping AS
 (SELECT  
  enterpriseid
 ,ownertype
 ,ownerid
 ,itemtype
 ,itemid
 ,rownum + 70000     new_pk
 FROM  
  (SELECT DISTINCT
    enterpriseid
   ,ownertype
   ,ownerid
   ,itemtype
   ,itemid
   FROM 
    eformdynamicfieldinstance
   )
)
;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX temp_pk_mapping_u1 ON temp_pk_mapping 
( enterpriseid
 ,ownertype
 ,ownerid
 ,itemtype
 ,itemid
)
;

UPDATE eformdynamicfieldinstance edfi
SET edfi.edfi_id =
 (SELECT new_pk
  FROM temp_pk_mapping map
  WHERE edfi.enterpriseid = map.enterpriseid 
  AND edfi.ownertype = map.ownertype  
  AND edfi.ownerid = map.ownerid  
  AND edfi.itemtype = map.itemtype  
  AND edfi.itemid = map.itemid
  )
;
```

Comment: nice solution will try

Comment: note I've just added an alias for new_pk in the table creation script